# Does a fresh install of Windows include a standard C++ library?

Tags: c++, c, windows, gcc, mingw

I'm doing some experiments with Mingw-w64 and it works great compiling regular C code, linking to the Windows system MSVCRT.DLL C library. But, if I compile C++ code, then mingw's g++ links to what looks like the GNU libstdc++ library. Why? This doesn't happen with regular C binaries. I see commerical Windows software all the time including the Microsoft "C++ redist" package, which I guess matches the version of Visual C++ they use to develop their software. So it seems like there's actually no C++ library by default on Windows. I'd like to use the "system" C++ library and not use the GNU one if possible to reduce the size of the binaries mingw is compiling. But, I also don't want a separate C++ redistributable that needs to be installed. Am I stuck with the GNU library?

Comment: There is no "system C++ library". `MSVCRT.DLL` is the Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime, it does not come pre-installed with Windows, so it needs to be installed. Chances are, other software has already installed it for you. On the other hand, if you compile your apps to use the static version of this library and not the dynamic version, then you don't need the DLL at all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Do you have a source on that claim? I find it hard to believe that Windows 10 doesn't ship with any MVCR by default.

Comment: The visual studio 2015+ runtime does come preinstalled on Windows 10 but gcc can only use libstdc++, you need to use visual studio or clang to use the visual studio runtime

Answer (score 2):

MinGW/MinGW-w64 build do use system standard libraries, that are part of Windows.

Visual C++ redistributable and runtime packages are only needed when sources are compiled with MSVC.

If your MinGW/MinGW-w64 build isn't statically linked you may need to ship libstd DLL files, but you can just put them in the same place as your .exe and/or .dll files, along with any other dependancy .dll files.

I actually love the fact that MinGW/MinGW-w64 builds don't need Visual C++ redistributable for several reasons:

- The user doesn't need to install yet another Visual C++ redistributable.
- The binaries are compact and don't depend on other Microsoft libraries except the ones in the operating system, which increases the chance of your software running well on different Windows versions.
- Install (and uninstall) instructions (or installer code) are easier as the Visual C++ redistributable dependancy doesn't need to be installed. In fact you can even run your software as a *portable app* without installer.

Comment: You can do the same with visual studio and put the runtime dlls in the same directory as your application